# Get not-URI location

Tags: c#, io, uri

When I do

```
string s = Path.Combine(Folders.Data, fileName);
```

I've got `file:\\...` (the URI location). How can I get `c:\...` (the *not-URI* location)?

**EDIT:**

The code for the Folders class is:

```
public static class Folders
{
    public static string App
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(
                Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Folders)).CodeBase
                );
        }
    }

    public static string Data
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(App, "Data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Folders`? Seems that `Folders.Data` contains `file://` already, `Path.Combine` just adds the last component.

Comment: What is `Folders` in this case?

Comment: `var x = return y`? That's new to me.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: sorry, there was a mistake! It's corrected now

Comment: `CodeBase` seems to return `file://`, you'll need to check if it's this way and strip off the unneeded parts. Maybe you'll need to unescape the URI, too.

Comment: The question could be: **Is there any way to get the app path without ´file:\\´?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path.Combine adds the last component, you need to remove file:\ from Folders.Data

You could do something like this

```
string s = Path.Combine(Folders.Data.Replace("file:\\",""), fileName);
```

For clear solution try to use Assembly.Location, as shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/26/57198.aspx) it is what you want.

---

So instead of using:

```
return Path.GetDirectoryName(
                Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Folders)).CodeBase
                );
```

Use:

```
return Path.GetDirectoryName(
                Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Folders)).Location
                );
```

Comment: Well, it could be done like this but I was looking for a cleaner solution (if it's possible).

Answer (score 2):

Get the location using the `Location` property instead:

```
var path = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Folders)).Location;
```

EDIT:

A few notes on the `Location` property [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx):

> Gets the path or UNC location of the
>   loaded file that contains the
>   manifest.
>
> ---
>
> [Returns] The location of the loaded file that
>   contains the manifest. If the loaded
>   file was shadow-copied, the location
>   is that of the file after being
>   shadow-copied. If the assembly is
>   loaded from a byte array, such as when
>   using the Load(Byte[]) method
>   overload, the value returned is an
>   empty string ("").
>
> ---
>
> To get the location before the file
>   has been shadow-copied, use the
>   CodeBase property.
>
> ---
>
> [Can raise] NotSupportedException 
>   The current assembly is a dynamic assembly,
>   represented by an AssemblyBuilder
>   object.

Comment: No problem; though, I'll edit as you don't even need the `Path.GetDirectoryName` since `Location` will always return a directory name.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `file://` URI, you can convert it to a normal path like this:

```
var fileUri = Folders.Data;
var asPath = new Uri(fileUri).LocalPath;
```